# How to create Kubernetes Cluster using Kops with insecure registry?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I have to create a cluster with support of insecure docker registry. I want to use `Kops` for this. Is there any way to create cluster with insecure registry using `Kops`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set insecure registry at cluster config edit time, after `kops create cluster ...` command (navigate to clusterSpec part of file):

```
$ kops edit cluster $NAME
...
 docker:
    insecureRegistry: registry.example.com
    logDriver: json-file
...
```

[Original link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/42#issuecomment-302073487)